# In-App purchase not working with 3G device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have developed an iPhone application which implements in-App purchase (server model). While testing I came across a very strange problem.
I have tested it on Wi-Fi network. The application works fine. All the downloads (using sandbox account), everything is tested successfully.

However, When I tried to download the same product using 3G connection, the error message (from App Store API) is prompted saying **"Wifi required. This item can only be downloaded over a wifi connection."**

I haven't found anything on the internet related to this problem. I am struck with this problem and trying to solve it since 2 days but still haven't found any solutions. Kindly help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It's the carriers/providers that impose the download limits, currently at 20MB's, over 3G I guess. So check your size of the downloads also check whether if you added any new network/wi-fi related key in info.plist

Comment: I think it will not be the caused. Since the error comes immediately when the Purchase module starts. In my case we are using Server Model of in-app purchase and download is possible only after payment is approved by Apple. However, the error comes when we proceed to pay.

Comment: No I haven't added this. Is it required?

Comment: No its not required... I am just verifying

Comment: I have send mail to Apple Support team, but haven't got any satisfactory response from them. It seems that there is an issue if you test the Ad hoc application; since no one is complaining regarding the same.